# ISPManager, WordPress проблема с выподом PHP скриптов

Tags: wordpress, ispmanager, isp

Хочу загрузить PHP скрипт, он не загружается и удаляется всё, что после него. Как будто и не было. Не понимаю почему.

Пользуюсь ISPManager'ом

Comment: Куда что и как ты загружаешь? Где и что ожидаешь увидеть? Причём тут ВП? Отредактируй свой вопрос.

Comment: @SeVlad ты спросил ровно то, что я поленился)))